# How to get a list of all owners of files in a directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, filesystem, quota

I am currently trying to fix my quota system. My problem is that I cannot determine if all files in a directory are owned by the same user. If possible is there a way to list the different owners of files in a directory (recursively).

e.g `get-owners-of DIRNAME`

Comment: So do you want to list all owners only, or all files with their owners, or all files owned by anyone other than a specific user?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `find` to print the user (owner) and group and then extract the uniq combinations e.g.

```
$ sudo find /var -printf '%u:%g\n' | sort -t: -u
_apt:root
avahi-autoipd:avahi-autoipd
clamav:adm
clamav:clamav
colord:colord
daemon:daemon
lightdm:lightdm
lp:lp
man:root
root:adm
root:crontab
root:lp
root:mail
root:mlocate
root:root
root:shadow
root:staff
root:syslog
root:utmp
root:whoopsie
speech-dispatcher:root
statd:nogroup
steeldriver:crontab
steeldriver:lightdm
steeldriver:steeldriver
syslog:adm
systemd-timesync:systemd-timesync
testuser:crontab
```

Comment: To evaluate directory *content* only (and not the root directory/-ies of the search itself) add `-mindepth 1` before `-printf`. And I wouldn't include `sudo` in the example when OP doesn't appear to work in a context where it's required.

Comment: Does `-t:` make a difference in this context?

Comment: @kasperd good point - probably not (it *might* affect the sort order - but we're not really interested in that)

Answer (score 20):

```
stat -c %U *
```

will list owners of all files.

This can be sorted and duplicates removed by piping it into `sort -u`:

```
stat -c %U * | sort -u
```

As pointed out by steeldriver, this is not recursive. I missed that this was asked for. It can be made recursive by enabling globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
stat -c %U **/* | sort -u
```

Alltogether, [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026939) is probably better and should be the accepted answer here :)

Comment: Won't that go over the command-line length, if there is a large number of files in the search? If so, then @steeldriver 's answer is better.

Comment: @CSM it will. Which is why I say that steeldrivers answer is a better one in many cases.

Comment: @CSM I guess if `ARG_MAX` is an issue you could do `printf '%s\0' **/* | xargs -0 stat -c %U` (since `printf` is a builtin, it shouldn't have the same length limitation)

Answer (score 7):

You may find it more efficient to directly search for the files *not* owned by the user ...

```
find /directory ! -user username -printf "%u %p\n"
```

Answer (score 4):

DIY method via Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys,os,pwd
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    username = pwd.getpwuid(os.stat(f).st_uid).pw_name
    print( ":".join([f,username])  )
```

This iterates over all filenames listed on command-line, gets UID of the file's owner, and using [pwd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html) module gets the username of the owner. After that, filename and username joined for pretty printing and separated via colon. Works as so:

```
$ ./get_owners.py /etc/* 
/etc/acpi:root
/etc/adduser.conf:root
/etc/alternatives:root
. . .
```